# Another "How can you do this without using a Subject<t>" Question for C#

Tags: signalr, c#-3.0, reactivex, signalr-2

There are lot's of questions here on StackOverflow going back 7 years about using ReactiveX and the **do** or **do not** of using *Subjects*.  Most of those questions end up being answered by folks arguing back and forth on philosophical grounds and end up being fairly light in actual examples and talking instead of the "correct" approach versus the "best" approach.

I have made up a simple example class that attempts to bridge from SignalR's IHubProxy.On to an IObservable.

Here is my class, please show me how to rewrite this class so that the Subject is not needed.

I just don't see a way to do so.

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using Owin;
using System;
using System.Reactive.Subjects;

namespace Acme.Core.SignalR
{
    public class SignalRPipe :IObservable<PipeCommand>, IDisposable
    {
        readonly IHubProxy _MyHub;
        readonly IDisposable _HubOnListener;

        // this next line is BAD and I want to get rid of it, but I can't figure out how.
        private readonly Subject<PipeCommand> subject = new Subject<PipeCommand>();

        private SignalRPipe() : base()
        {
        }

        private SignalRPipe( IHubProxy hub ) : this()
        {
            _MyHub = hub;
            _HubOnListener = _MyHub.On<PipeCommand>( "OnPipeCommand" , OnPipeCommand );
        }

        private void OnPipeCommand( PipeCommand obj )
        {
            subject.OnNext( obj );
        }

        public IDisposable Subscribe( IObserver<PipeCommand> observer )
        {
            return subject.Subscribe( observer );
            //var rtrn = Observable.Create<PipeCommand>( ob => {observer.Subscribe(t=> {  }, ,  } );
            //return rtrn;
        }


        #region IDisposable Support
        private bool disposedValue = false; // To detect redundant calls

        protected virtual void Dispose( bool disposing )
        {
            if ( !disposedValue )
            {
                disposedValue = true;
                if ( disposing )
                {
                    _HubOnListener.Dispose();
                    subject.Dispose();
                }

            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in Dispose(bool disposing) above.
            Dispose( true );
        }

        #endregion

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

That turned out to be alot easier than I had originally expected. Kept digging at it and came up with this answer...

Will this work (don't worry about "is it right")?

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client;
using System;

namespace Acme.Core.SignalR
{
    public class SignalRPipe : IObservable<PipeCommand>
    {
        readonly IHubProxy _MyHub;

        private SignalRPipe() : base()
        {
        }

        private SignalRPipe( IHubProxy hub ) : this()
        {
            _MyHub = hub;
        }

        public IDisposable Subscribe( IObserver<PipeCommand> observer )
        {
            var rtrn = _MyHub.On<PipeCommand>( "OnPipeCommand" , pc => observer.OnNext( pc ) );
            return rtrn;
        }

    }

}
```